# PHP If Else Error

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, do-while

I'm trying to fill a table with data from a database using mysqli and php. Using the following code:

```
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) > 0) {
    do {
    <tr> 
      <td> echo $rows['COL 1']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 2']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 3']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 4']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 5']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 6']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 7']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 8']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 9']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 10']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 11']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 12']; </td>
      <td> echo $rows['COL 13']; </td>

    </tr>
     }  while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
}

else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
?>
```

I get an error and nothing shows up on the website. I'm certain this has to do with the php tags, but I can't figure out how to use them properly. I've also tried:

```
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) > 0) {
    do { ?>
    <tr> 
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 1'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 2'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 3'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 4'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 5'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 6'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 7'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 8'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 9'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 10'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 11'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 12'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 13'];?> </td>

    </tr>
     }  <?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));?>
     </table>
}
<?php 
else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: On you first iteration, `$rows` is not set. You should use a normal `while` loop with the condition a the start.

Comment: You're injecting pure HTML into PHP.

Comment: What is the value of `$search_query`? The naming suggests this is the query, _not_ the queries result...

Comment: Did you execute a `mysqli_query` somewhere?

Comment: you have syntax error after </tr> }; you show have <? before } not after it.

Comment: Thanks, it does make more sense to use a while loop. search_query =$mysqli->query($search_sql); I didn't post the entire code to save room, as everything was working until I used the do-while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with just a normal while loop.

A do while will execute the do part first so $rows will be undefined.

```
 <?php 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($search_query) > 0) { ?>
         <table>
         <?php while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query)) { ?>
        <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 1'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 2'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 3'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 4'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 5'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 6'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 7'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 8'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 9'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 10'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 11'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 12'];?> </td>
          <td><?php echo $rows['COL 13'];?> </td>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
         </table>

    <?php }
    else {
        echo "No results found.";
    }
    ?>
```

You also has a closing bracket outside your PHP tags in your second example. Turning on error reporting would have given you an informative error message.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Comment: This does not explain the OPs issue, though certainly you are right that a `while` loop makes more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 

  $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { ?>
     <table>
     <?php while ($rows=$result) { ?>
    <tr> 
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 1'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 2'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 3'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 4'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 5'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 6'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 7'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 8'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 9'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 10'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 11'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 12'];?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['COL 13'];?> </td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
     </table>

<?php }
else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
?>
```